# App crashes after displaying a ModalViewController and going to background state

Tags: ios, crash, modalviewcontroller

My iOS app keeps crashing. I found the way I could make it crash consistently. I repeated the operation multiple times and I get the same crash log every single time.

The crash happens if I do the following: launch the app, use it a bit (optional), go to the main screen, open a modal ViewController, dismiss it, keep using the app (optional), close the app (press home button, not kill the app), wait a bit (optional), re-open the app. When the app is re-opened, it crashes after 1 second. Note that where you are in the app when you leave it does not cause/prevent the crash. No matter where you are on the app, it crashes the same way. If I use the app and don't open the modal VC, I can send it in background and re-open it with no problem.

Here is some of the crash log I get every time (I took out what I thought was not related, I can provide the full log):

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) 
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000 
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 
Thread 0 Crashed: 
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x317d332c __pthread_kill + 8 
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ed0208 pthread_kill + 48 
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ec9298 abort + 88 
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36d56f64 abort_message + 40 
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36d54346 _ZL17default_terminatev + 18 
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x35321350 _objc_terminate + 140 
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36d543be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70 
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36d5444a std::terminate() + 14 
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36d5581e __cxa_rethrow + 82 
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x353212a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6 
10  CoreFoundation                  0x37572506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398 
11  CoreFoundation                  0x37572366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98 
12  GraphicsServices                0x33d31432 GSEventRunModal + 130 
13  UIKit                           0x3131ecce UIApplicationMain + 1074 
14  ***my app name**                0x0006f140 0x6b000 + 16704 
15  ***my app name**                0x0006d5f0 0x6b000 + 9712
```

It's hard to provide some code, and I don't even know what I could possibly give..

I'd love some help, I have no idea why this is happening..

Comment: Do you have breakpoints set on Objective-C exceptions?

Comment: Huh, I don't know, I guess not ? Could you explain a bit ?

Comment: Search on "breakpoint navigator" in the documentation part of the Organizer window.  You should see entries come up in the tools guides that explain it with pictures better than I can in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feels to me like some cleanup is happening whilst you're in the background. If it's not iOS 6 then check what you;re doing to handle viewDidUnload and in any version, check what you're doing in viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear and viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post the modal view controller code if I can't solve the issue.

Comment: OK, problem solved. I was registering for an observer on my AppDelegate, and I was never removing it. I now register for it in viewWillAppear (instead of viewDidLoad), and removing it in viewWillDisappear. I'll accept your answer as it lead me on the way to find the source of the problem. What's strange though is that the error was kind of explicit in the simulator, but not at all when running on a device...